# What does Drop root mean in Linux

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sudo, root, uid

I am fairly new to working on Linux/Ubuntu and I came across the statement
**Application need to start with root privilege, then drop the root**

I am wondering what does the above statement mean?

Also when I executed the application binary, I could see the following statements being printed on the console

```
Warning: group= user1 not found in /etc/group file
Warning: UID 1041 not known in the system. Test may fail.
drop root to uid [1041] complete
```

Could someone please help me understand this? Thanks

Comment: In this context "drop" means "change to user".

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you should start the application using root privileges and then afterwards, don't use root privileges for any other commands.

If you are using `sudo` to launch the application, you can run the following to "drop" the root privileges:

```bsh
sudo -k
```

This will revoke the user's cached credentials.  So the next time you try to run a command with `sudo`, you will have to enter your password.